# Qual a finalidade de usar a função filter_input

Tags: php

Por que é mais seguro utilizar a função `filter_input`, do que usar simplesmente usar as variáveis globais (`$_SERVER`, `$_GET`, `$_POST`)?

Comment: Você em segurança sobre ataques de injeção de código ou sobre boas práticas para evitar warnings?

Comment: segurança contra SQL injection

Comment: Estou querendo evitar SQL injection, alguém pode me ajudar para utilizar o filter_input ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Referência para filter:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Minha opinião é que você deve sempre usá-lo (a extensão filter em geral). Há pelo menos três razões para isso:

1 - Filtrar entrada de dados é algo que você deve sempre fazer. Desde que a função dá-lhe essa capacidade não há realmente nenhuma razão para encontrar outras formas de higienização de entrada. Uma vez que é uma extensão do filtro também será muito mais rápido e, provavelmente, mais seguro do que a maioria das soluções de PHP por aí, o que certamente não faz mal. A única exceção é se você precisa de um filtro mais especializado. Mesmo assim, você deve pegar o valor usando o filtro FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW.

2 - Há um monte de coisas na extensão de filter. Ele pode te salvar horas de escrever filtros e código de validação. Claro, ele não cobre todos os casos.

3 - Usando a função é muito bom para quando você está depurando seu código. Quando a função é usada você sabe exatamente o que a entrada será. Por exemplo, se você usar o FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT filtro, então você pode ter certeza de que a entrada será um número - sem [`SQL Injection`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php), nenhum código HTML ou Javascript, etc...