# Validar captcha com PHP

Tags: php, html, captcha

Tenho um captcha num formulário onde é exibida uma imagem com 5 valores gerados aleatoriamente. Como faço para validar o captcha e somente enviar o contato se o valor digitado no input for igual ao gerado pela imagem?

Trecho do formulário que possui o captcha:

```
<div class="col one-fourth" style="padding: 0 3px;">
    <img src="captcha.php"/>
</div>
<div class="col one-fourth" style="padding: 0 3px;">
    <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" placeholder="Digite o código ao lado" class="campos_form" maxlength="5" required/>
</div>
```

Esse é o arquivo que chamo que gera a imagem com o captcha:

```
<?php
session_start();
$codigoCaptcha = substr(md5( time()) ,0,5);
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $codigoCaptcha;

$imagemCaptcha = imagecreatefrompng("imagens/fundocaptcha.png");
$fonteCaptcha = imageloadfont("anonymous.gdf");
$corCaptcha = imagecolorallocate($imagemCaptcha,46,139,87);

imagestring($imagemCaptcha,$fonteCaptcha,15,5,$codigoCaptcha,$corCaptcha);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($imagemCaptcha);
imagedestroy($imagemCaptcha);
?>
```

Como verifico se o usuario inseriu corretamente? 
Posso usar o `$_SESSION['captcha']` para comparar o valor? E como capturo o valor do `input`?

Comment: Oi, @PHP, não precisa colocar tags no título, só se for de maneira orgânica. Normalmente é melhor descrever o problema, os frequentadores do site já filtram as perguntas que querem responder usando o sistema de tags que o [pt.so] oferece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,

pode sim, capture o valor do input utilizando

```
// pode ser feito assim...
$captchaEnviado = $_POST['captcha'];

//ou assim... que é mais seguro...
$captchaEnviado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'captcha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if($captchaEnviado == $_SESSION['captcha'] ){
  //ok... continua...
}
else{
  //valor errado... trata como achar que deve....
}
```

mais infos sobre o `filter_input` [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)

e como mencionado [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20641/qual-a-finalidade-de-usar-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-filter-input) aqui mesmo no SO

Comment: Aqui: $captchaEnviado = $_POST['captcha']; , posso declarar isso no mesmo arquivo no formulario? Ou preciso passar via POST para outra pagina?

Comment: @PHPdeveloper vc pode fazer dos dois modos, se o post for feito a variável estará lá, mas é importante que vc recebe o parâmetro (eu ainda indico que seja utilziando o filter_input por segurança, deixei os dois métodos para exemplo). Lembre-se de validar se ele já foi apssado para não gerar erros no seu código.